# Swift - Operators + Variables

Tags: swift

I'm not able to do with swift : String1 = - String2 + 2

Actually :

```
var SetupTimer = "123"

var currentTime = 0
```

In an other fonction i do this :

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    var itemSelected = food[row]
    itemLabel.text = itemSelected
    bb = itemSelected 
}

SetupTimer = bb
```

And finally i want to do that  :

```
var currentTime = - SetupTimer + 10
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

EDIT :

```
func CountDown()
{        
    if let timerAsInt = SetupTimer.toInt()
    {
        var currentTime = -timerAsInt + 10
    }

    currentTime = currentTime + 1

    self.lbltimer.text = (String(10 - currentTime))
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error? Please edit your question with more details. And format the code correctly please.

Comment: Why would you be negating strings? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What is the content of `bb`?

Comment: @appzYourLife Post edited

Comment: bb can be : 30 or 60 or 90 or 120

Comment: Please try debug mode or add `debugPrint(bb)` and verify it.

Comment: I have already test the value of bb with a textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same preconditions of the answer by Craig Otis.

So, if you have a `String` `setupTimer` that does represent an integer

```
let setupTimer = "123"
```

then you can write:

### Swift 2.0

```
if let timerAsInt = Int(setupTimer) {
    var currentTime = -timerAsInt + 10
}
```

### Swift 1.2

```
if let timerAsInt = setupTimer.toInt() {
    var currentTime = -timerAsInt + 10
}
```

Hope this helps.

### Update

If you want to update your own `currentTime` variable this is the code

```
if let timerAsInt = setupTimer.toInt() {
    currentTime = -timerAsInt + 10
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, "Cannot find an initializer for type 'Int' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'"

Comment: My code is for `Swift 2.0`, I am adding the `Swift 1.2` version now.

Comment: @PenardCorentin: ok try now.

Comment: Well it doesn't work, i think i didn't tell enough things to resolve my problem, i have add the rest of the code to my post...

Comment: Oh gosh, i forgot the caps ... well i try to run this now

Comment: Well it doesn't increments the currentTime is always 10
i add code to my post

Comment: @PenardCorentin: If you want to change your own `currentTime` variable then use the new code I added at the end of my answer. Finally you should read the Swift Programming Guide, these are fundamentals that are explained very well in the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: Well lbltimer.text should be 10 - currenTime = 10 - (-60) = 70